# Jquery .click() get superior this

Tags: jquery, click, this

Inside a method of my class I have:

```
this.background.click(function() {
    this.terminate();
});
```

Obviously `this.terminate();` doesn't work because `this` refers to `this.background` inside `jquery.click` function. How do I have to write for get `this` from superior class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable containing the outer `this`:

```
var self = this;
this.background.click(function() {
    self.terminate();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
this.background.click( $.proxy( this.terminate, this ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make like @Andrew said, or can make "yourObject.terminate();"

Ex:

```
var yourObject = {
    background: $("#background"),
    terminate: function ()
    {
        alert("do something...");
    },
    addEvents: function ()
    {
        this.background.click(function()
        {
            yourObject.terminate();
        });
    }
};


$(function()
{
    yourObject.addEvents();
});
```

for improve, ensure the 'background' selector exists (if javascript load before html), and use jquery "live()" or "delegate()" or "on()" to attach events in the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use bind

```
 $(".detailsbox").click(function(evt){
     test.bind($(this))();
  });
  function test()
  {
     var $this = $(this);
  }
```